# Laravel 5.5 how can access to one value of an array in blade view

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to access a value from an array in my blade view.
My arrays from controller:

```
array:2 [▼
"chartAllAlarm" => alarmDashboardChart {#298 ▶}
"prodCounter" => array:1 [▼
  0 => {#303 ▼
  +"production": 3580
  +"preProduction": 0
  +"test": 0
  +"maintenance": 6
  +"decommissioned": 403
}
```

]
]

My view:

```
<h3 class="font-weight-semibold mb-0">{{ $prodCounter[production] }}</h3>
```

Error in Laravel:

> Use of undefined constant production - assumed 'production' (View:

Can someone help me?

Comment: You missed the quotes on `$prodCounter[production]`. Try `$prodCounter['production']`

Comment: But if what you showing is a dump of  `$prodCounter`, you have to access the previous indexes before `$prodCounter['prodCounter'][0]->production` and access to production attributte, since you have an object there

Comment: using    {{ $prodCounter['prodCounter'][0]->production }}     Laravel says: Undefined index: prodCounter (View:

Comment: Well... then try `$prodCounter[0]->production`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try:

```
<h3 class="font-weight-semibold mb-0">{{ $prodCounter['production'] }}</h3>
```

and Laravel return this error:

> Undefined index: production (View:

Well, I solved it using a collection instead of an array. In the recovery view, the data looks like this:

```
{{ $prodCounter->production }}
```

Thank you all for the support. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Are you using guzzle in backend?

i have my code like this in blade.php

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="PreviredID">ID Registro</label>
            <input type="int" name="PreviredID" readonly required value="{{ $posts->PreviredID}}" class="form-control">   
            <h3></h3>
        </div>
```

can you try with this!